# JSONDecodable and required init

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.2

I've created a network manager that gets a JSON response and converts it in to a Swift object,

```
protocol HTTPResponse: Codable {
        
}

class UserResponse: HTTPResponse {
   var name: String?
}

let responseObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: response.data!)
```

where `T` is an HTTPResponse decendent

I need to be able to create an 'empty' UserResponse object, an instance where all the class variables are `nil`

I changed `HTTPResponse` from `protocol` to `class` and added an empty `required init() {}` to it.

This allows me to invoke `T()` and get an instance of `UserResponse` but now `JSONDecoder` is no longer parsing the JSON, it also creates instances where all variables are `nil`

How can I achieve the end result where `JSONDecoder` works well, and I can create stub instances of my `HTTPResponse` decedent classes?

I'm working with swift 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the initialiser requirement to the protocol:

```
protocol HTTPResponse: Codable {
    init()
}
```

Then, add a `required init() { ... }` to `UserResponse` and all the conformers. Each conformer can decide what a "stub" response means for them.

After that `T()` will work, given that `T` is a generic parameter with the constraint `<T: HTTPResponse>`. This might seem strange as you are initialising a protocol. But actually, since [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), `T` will never be `HTTPResponse`, and will always be a concrete class that conforms to `HTTPResponse`.